# A centeral element in a non-commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a non-commutative without identity element and let $a\in R$ be such that $\langle a\rangle=\{na+ra: n\in \mathbb{Z} \And r\in R\}$, the two side ideal of $R$ generated by $a$. Can we deduced that $a$ is a centeral element?

Comment: I think you probably actually mean "not necessarily with unit" rather than "without identity," is that right? Surely if you could prove it for "rngs" you would not randomly omit rings with identity, right.

Comment: In that case $\mathbb H$ would be a counterexample. I have gone ahead and contrived an example without identity, though.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, let $\sigma:F\to F$ be a field endomorphism such that $[F:\sigma (F)] > 1$.

Then let $R=F[x;\sigma]$ be the noncommutative twisted polynomial ring with the twist $xa=\sigma(a)x$ for every $a\in F$.

Now with $S=\langle x \rangle \lhd R$. $S$ furnishes an example of a noncommutative ring without identity where $\langle x\rangle\subseteq S$ is two-sided but $x$ is not central.